# How to open popup within a popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to open popup in another window open popup.

Please check code-

**myjavascript.js**

```
var win = null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll){
    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
    settings =
    'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
    win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings)
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="NewWindow('popup1.html','name','500','500','yes');return false" class="link-2">My Account</a>
```

**popup1.html**

```
<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="NewWindow('popup2.html','name','500','500','yes');return false" class="link-2">Click to open popup2</a>
```

**popup2.html**

```
<h1>You are now popup2.html page</h1>
```

Above code is working for me but the second popup not open. please check and let me know.

Thanks
@chatfun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same identifier for both `window.open(mypage,myname,settings)`.

Change the `name` in the second invocation:

**index.html**

`<a href="#" onclick="NewWindow('popup1.html','name','500','500','yes');return false" class="link-2">My Account</a>`

**popup1.html**

`<a href="#" onclick="NewWindow('popup2.html','NEWNAME','500','500','yes');return false" class="link-2">Click to open popup2</a>`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Function is there please cehck `NewWindow()` in myjavascript.js

Comment: I have not mentioned but `js` file already have there `<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes I know, I'm saying that you're including the function in `index.html` but not in `popup1.html`.

Comment: I include the js in both and try it with chrome and works ok. Did you check the error showed in js console?

Comment: Check now my updated question. I told you my code is working. but the second popup not opening. it is opening within the first popup.

Comment: Ahhh right, now I get it, the problem is the content of popup2.html is showed in the same window as popup1.html... I update my answer.